# How to upsert inside a nested object in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've a collection named **bikes** like this:

```
{
    "fname": "foo",
    "indian":"hero-corps"
    "brands": [
        {
            "region": "asia",
            "type": "terrain"
        }
    ]
}
```

And getting a json through post like this (let's name it **jsonBody**):

```
{
  "indian": "hero-corps",
  "someKeyA": "someValueA",
}
```

I'm using the following mongo update query :

```
 db.collection(bikes).update({"indian":"hero-corps"},{$set:jsonBody}, {upsert:true});
```

The problem is that it's upserting inside the main object, I want to upsert only inside the nested object **brands** with the **jsonBody**. How do I achieve that ?

Actual result:

```
{
    "fname": "foo",
    "indian": "hero-corps",
    "brands": [
       {
          "region": "asia",
          "type": "terrain"
       }
    ],
    "indian": "hero-corps",
    "someKeyA": "someValueA",
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "fname": "foo",
    "indian": "hero-corps",
    "brands": [
        {
            "region": "asia",
            "type": "terrain",
            "someKeyA": "someValueA",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your actual results vs. desired results.

Comment: @DaveCoast: added actual and expected results

Comment: Please review the $set doc - https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/. You need to specify what needs to be updated (probably the brands array) - see the Set Elements in Arrays section in the doc.

Comment: Is "brand" one element array?

Comment: And how do you know in which sub-document you want to add a key/value?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if that is what you want to do but i'm sure that it will give the format you want.

db.collection(bikes).update({"indian":"hero-corps"},{$push:{"brands":jsonBody}}, {upsert:true});